# Nan error of gradients in Theano

Tags: theano

When I construct such a computation

```
p_1 = 1 / (1 + T.exp(-T.dot(x, (w1-w2)) - (b1-b2)))
```

w1, w2, b1, b2 are parameters. And I construct a cross-entropy as loss function.

But when I take gradients

```
T.grad(loss,[w1, b1, w2, b2])
```

All the resulted gradients are nan.

Is there any possible reasons for this problem? And any solution to it?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: It could be because of the weights initialization or some other metaparameter setting. Are you sure is not the parameters or p_1 the ones who are NaN and because of that the gradient isNaN too?

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution. Basically numerical instability. By changing log sigmoid to softplus solved this problem.